# Ordering and slicing a django queryset

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a query which orders the objects and then returns the first 100.

```
Orders.objects.order_by('date', 'time')[:100]
```

However I get this error.

```
Cannot reorder a query once a slice has been taken.
```

How would I make this query?

Edit:
Context

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django_tables2 import RequestConfig
from .models import Order
from .tables import OrderTable

def order(request):
    table = OrdersTable(Orders.objects.order_by('date', 'time')[:100])
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'view_orders/index.html', {'table': table})

# app/tables.py
import django_tables2 as tables
from .models import Order

class OrderTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        attrs = {'class': 'table', 'id': 'Order'}
```

Comment: That query and the slicing should work. 
Can you show the whole code involved? Are you using a manager?

Comment: I'm using django-tables2

Comment: And what about the code for the `OrderTable`? Are you sure it isn't expecting a queryset while you are passing a list?

Comment: I don't think so, it worked fine for .objects.all(). Added code for OrderTable

Comment: I think it is django-tables giving this error, please check [this](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/issues/142) issue.

Comment: Yeah, it worked for `objects.all()` as it returns a queryset. Once you slice the queryset you get a list. And that seems to be the problem. Why do you want to slice to 100 anyway? Wouldn't paginating your table be the more natural behaviour: http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/pagination.html#pagination ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django-tables2 is giving this error, it needs to call order on the query however you are passing a already sliced list instead. A work around is explained in this [reported issue](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/issues/142). You can also use the render portion only as in example provided in [doc](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/tutorial.html):

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def people(request):
    return render(request, 'people.html', {'people': Person.objects.all()})
```

for the template:

```
{# tutorial/templates/people.html #}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'django_tables2/themes/paleblue/css/screen.css' %}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        {% render_table people %}
    </body>
</html>
```